# ng-repeat view "lagging" behind the actual model?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
{{vm.regions}}

<div ng-repeat="region in vm.regions">
 {{region}}
</div>
```

On button presses, the model a.k.a vm.regions gets updated in the controller. For example `vm.regions = []`.

I can see that the array `{{vm.regions}}` is instantly updated, but the elements in the div take at least a second to update, meaning you can see old elements  for a bit in the newly updated list, for example.

What is causing this?

Comment: It should be instant. Is this all of your code? Or does it look slightly differently? The only lag you might experience is with the watchers, try using `{{::region}}` for that

Comment: The vm.regions is updated in an sync operation actually, but again, I see that the array is updated instantly while the ng-repeat list takes time to update.

Comment: not enough code to replicate it

Answer (score 0):

It is in AngularJs Best Practices to always add "track by $index" in order to inprove performances.

```html
{{vm.regions}}

<div ng-repeat="region in vm.regions track by $index">
 {{region}}
</div>
```

Link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: you can combine that with a One time binding as explained by Aleksey Solovey

Comment: The ng-repeat will recreat the div, the region attributes inside the div will not move. It should be ok with what you want. However, could you try to make a plunker recreating your problem ? what's the size of your vm.regions array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using vs-repeat. It applies virtual scrolling to ng-repeat which increases its performance drastically even if you are not using one time binding.

http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=8